# Powershell custom object multi-line string

Tags: oracle, powershell, multiline

I have a query output (PL/SQL) using SQLPLUS in Powershell (using a script) which exists of multiple lines.

[image: Query output]

I would like to print these multiple lines within my custom object properties, but the query is wrapped on 1 single line. How can I fix this?

[image]

code:

```
foreach ($proc in $process_id) {

    foreach ($id in $service) {

        if ($id.ProcessId -eq $proc.RawValue) {

            foreach ($time in $processor_time) {

                $path = $proc.Path.Replace("\id process","\% processor time")
                if ($time.Path -eq $path -and $time.CookedValue -gt 0) {
                    $cpu = [Math]::Round($time.CookedValue / $env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, 1)

                    #if cpu usage > 1%
                    if ($cpu -gt 1) {

                        $klant = $id.Name.Substring(13)
                        $sqlQuery = "
                                    set serveroutput on
                                    set feedback off
                                    set pagesize 100
                                    set heading off
                                    SELECT SQL_TEXT
                                      FROM SYS.V_`$SQL S, SYS.ALL_USERS U, V`$SESSION SN
                                     WHERE S.PARSING_USER_ID = U.USER_ID
                                       AND SN.sql_hash_value = S.hash_value
                                       AND SN.sql_address = S.address
                                     ORDER BY S.LAST_LOAD_TIME;
                                     "
                        $sqlOutput = $sqlQuery | sqlplus -silent "sys/d20K27hD@$($klant) as sysdba"
                        $item += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Klant="$($klant)"; 'CPU %'="$($cpu)"; Query="$($sqlOutput)"}
                        $item
                    }
                }
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you used (not a screenshot of it, post the actual code as text)

Comment: You're not using the original, multi-line string (`$sqlQuery`) in your output object, but the result of sending that to your  `sqlplus` command (I don't know what that does), `$sqlOutput`. Note that if you do have multi-line strings in property values and you're using _tabular_ output (`Format-Table`, the default with up to 4 properties), you'll need to pipe to `Format-Table -Wrap` to see all lines.

Comment: Since the output gets smooshed to one line, you could re-split it up if you want to see it in multiline format. For example if it's tab-separated: `$sqlOutput -replace '\t',"\`r\`n" | where {$_}`, though you will lose your indentation.